# Getting user quota stats

Tags: php

I have the following function to collect quota information for the given user and return the information on a "ready to use" array:

```
/* Get User Quota Information
 *
 * Prepare and array with the user's account disk space information
 * by ascertaining the amount of space available on its quota,
 * the used space from that quota and free space remaining.
 *
 * @param string $user The system user name
 *
 * @return array
 */
function getUserQuotaInfo($user) {

  $quota = exec("quota -s -u ".$user);            // query server

  $quota = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", ' ', $quota); // clear spaces

  $arr = explode(' ', $quota);

  $freeSpace = str_replace('M', '', $arr[3]) - str_replace('M', '', $arr[2]);

  return array(
    "total" => $arr[3],
    "used"  => $arr[2],
    "free"  => $freeSpace.'M'
  );
}
```

The function is working well and giving the expected results, but there's a lot going on to manipulate the information in order to have it ready to present to the user.

Is there any optimization that can be done as to reduce the possibilities of failure on this function as well as simplifying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to secure that `$user` does not do damage through your `exec` call. Also, you should check if your `$arr` actually has the required data.

As for optimization, replacing multiple spaces and dashes with single spaces and then exploding such strings seems to me slower than just splitting the string right away, using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$arr = preg_split("/[\s-]+/", $quota);
```

However, you should still check that `count($arr) > 3`.

I must say that I am a bit surprised to see this work for you. That means that the user under which PHP is running has the permission to see **other users'** quota. IMO, web server should not be allowed as much.

A better way to do this is to dump all users' quotas in some text file (i.e., using [`repquota`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_repquota.htm) command; see an example on how to use it [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-104-4/#5-repquota)), via a cron job run as root, and then make the script that only parses that file.

Or, quite similarly, your cron job can make a file with all the data, i.e., create `quota-data.php` like this:

```
<?php

$quota_data = array(
  'zuul' => array(
    'total' => ...,
    'used'  => ...,
    'free'  => ...,
  ),
  ...
);

?>
```

which you then just include in your script and use the data.

Which of these two approaches is better depends on how often the data is read from the web. If rarely, the text file approach is better, so that parsing is done only when really needed; if often, the second approach is better, as it parses the data only once per update.

Comment: Apart from the advices given, thank you for the `preg_split()` suggestion, it is indeed a great improvement to reduce the amount of code. **Note:** This function is part of a PHP class that receives parameters from a configuration file, actually the `$user` only holds one value per each implementation of this "application". The user running the application cannot view any information about other users. Nor the server allows it!

Comment: So, `$user` is the user running the application? In that case, `quota -v` should do, without `-u $user`. Note that `-v` is not "human readable", which makes it easier to parse (no need to worry if you have "M", "G",...).

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of niggles I have with your code. For a start, you're just assuming the `exec` call will be successful, even though you don't do anything to *sanitize* the input argument: `$user`. As Vedran pointed out, this is where `escapeshellarg` should be used.

But please, also [read the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), and look at the function signature of `exec`:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

On the doc pages, you'll see that the string that this function returns is only *the last line of output*, not the entire output at all:

> Return Values
>
> The last line from the result of the command.

Hence, I'd write your code like so:

```
exec('quota -s -u '.escapeshellarg($user), $output, $status);
if ($status !== 0)
{//0 signals successful run
    throw new RuntimeException('exec call failed, with status :'.$status);
}
$output = array_map('cleanFunc', $output);

//the cleanFunc needn't be more than:
function cleanFunc($string)
{
    return preg_split('/[\s-]+/',$string);
}
```

The rest is OK, not great, but OK. What you're doing is, essentially, using a screwdriver as a chisel. PHP is not the best tool for the job at hand, so whichever way you look at it, your code will never be *as good a sollution as possible*.
But that's not the point...

Comment: Thank you for the the advices given, just a side note on the function `CleanFunc`: you need to replace `preg_split('/[\s-]+/',' ',$string)` with `preg_split('/[\s-]+/', $string)` since the string with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is the second parameter.

Comment: @Zuul: of course, I edited my answer... I got confused looking at your `str_replace`, so used it like it were `preg_replace`... ah well... it's all fixed now